# Android -Simple random app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app and have a little bit of a problem.

Android Monitor :

```html
08-31 07:41:59.705 10118-10118/com.example.user.rotateit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.rotateit/com.example.user.rotateit.HasilActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.user.rotateit.HasilActivity.onCreate(HasilActivity.java:24)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

HasilActivity.Java :

```html
public class HasilActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hasil);

        int choice = 0;
        final Random random = new Random();
        choice = random.nextInt(2)+0;


        EditText et_black = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_black);
        EditText et_white = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_white);
        TextView tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        
        String et_blackText = et_black.getText().toString();
        String et_whiteText = et_white.getText().toString();


        if (choice == 0) {
            tv_result.setText(et_blackText);
        }
        if (choice == 1) {
            tv_result.setText(et_whiteText);
        }
    }
}
```

XML (activity_hasil):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.rotateit.HasilActivity">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        ImageView btn_start = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HasilActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

XML (activity_main) :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#42079D"
    tools:context="com.example.user.rotateit.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_black"
            style="@style/EditText1"
            android:background="#0B0503"
            android:textColor="#FEFCFB"

            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_white"
            style="@style/EditText1"
            android:background="#FEFCFB"
            android:textColor="#0B0503"

            />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_start"
            android:id="@+id/btn_start"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

MANIFEST.XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.rotateit">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HasilActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app always stops working when I run the program.
This is the whole program. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the editText.

Basically, i want the program itself be able to show what the user typed in, in random. So, there are two EditTexts, et_black and et_white. the user will typed in any text in both of the editText, than the program will show either et_black or et_white.

Just started learning android studio.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: what is et_hitam?
add your error

Comment: If that's the complete code, it can't work. If it's the incomplete code, we can't say what's the problem. Anyway, there should be a `setContentView()` somewhere before `findViewById()` and both should be in an Activity's `onCreate()`.

Comment: is this code inside the `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Your if part should be this:
`if (choice == 0) {
    tv_result.setText(""+et_black.getText());
}`

Comment: @TasosMoustakas tried that, still error.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen i added the complete code just now.

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty yup

Comment: @Yoni "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: one of your editText and textView is not set or not found please check your xml

Comment: Try casting `random.nextInt(2)+0;` to an `int` before assigning it to `choice` variable

Comment: @Gerry08 on which line the NullPointerException occurs?

Comment: @TasosMoustakas tried that too. btw, i've posted the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `String` with the text inside the et_black `TextEdit` object. After that you can assign this String to the tv_result `TextView`

```
String et_blackText = et_black.getText().toString();

if (choice == 0 || choice == 1) {
    tv_result.setText(et_blackText);
}
```

In addition, you have to create the following objects in your XML

```
EditText et_black = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_black);
EditText et_white = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_white);
TextView tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
```

`R.id.et_black`,`R.id.et_white`,`R.id.tv_result` are not created in your HasilXML file

Comment: Actually    R.id.et_black,     R.id.et_white  are in activity_main.XML .    While  tv_result is in activity_hasil.XML

Comment: i added what i want the program will be able to do.

Comment: Why does HasilActivity extends MainActivity? Change it to AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put the EditText et_black as  the text of the TextView.
I won't say anything else, just..carefully check your code!!

PS post you manifest.xml

Comment: added manifest.xml . yes, i'm trying to put et_black as the textview.